# Use divergence theorem to compute acceleration of a sphere

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, gauss-law, vector-fields

Suppose we have $\vec{F}$ being the force on a proof mass $m$ in the field of a mass $M$ with mass density $\rho(\vec{r})$ given by $\vec{F}(\vec{r})= m\vec{g}(\vec{r})$ and $\vec{g}(\vec{r}) = \nabla \phi (\vec{r})$ which follows the equation $\textrm{div } \vec{g}(\vec{r}) = -4\pi \gamma\rho(\vec{r})$.

---

Now I am asked to use the divergence theorem to compute $\vec{g}(\vec{r})$ for a sphere with radius $R$ and homogeneous mass density $\rho(\vec{r})= \rho_0$. For that we are supposed to use $\vec{g}(\vec{r})= g(r)ê_r$ and integrate over a spherical integration area with radius $r_0$. As a hint we have been told to look at the cases $r_0 ><R$.

---

Since this is from my first physics class, I'm feeling quite confused but I tried to come up with approaches. First of all, would it be correct to use divergence theorem to evaluate $$\iint_{\partial S}\vec{F}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{A}= \iiint_{S}\textrm{div }\vec{g}(\vec{r})dV$$ where I can evaluate the triple integral on the intervals $[0,r_0][0,\pi][0,2\pi]$? However, using this approach leads to the integral being 0 so that a distinction between the cases would not make sense. I hope that anybody can help me understand this task more or find an understandable approach.

Comment: If you are familiar with electrostatics, the question basically boils down to finding the field due to a uniformly charged sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the divergence theorem is very useful here.

you can start by looking at $r_0<R$, and take $V$ to be the volume of a ball with radius $r_0$:
$$
\oint_{\partial V} g(r) \hat{e}_r \cdot \vec{dS} = \int_V \nabla \cdot \vec{g} dV \\
4 \pi r_0^2 g(r_0) = -\int_V 4 \pi G\rho(r) dV \\
g(r_0) = -r_0^{-2}\rho(r_0) G\int_V  dV = -\rho(r_0) \cdot \frac{4 \pi G}{3}r_0
$$

and simmilarly when $r_0>R$:
$$
\oint_{\partial V} g(r) \hat{e}_r \cdot \vec{dS} = \int_V \nabla \cdot \vec{g} dV \\
4 \pi r_0^2 g(r_0) = -\int_V 4 \pi G \rho(r) dV \\
g(r_0) = -r_0^{-2}\rho(r_0) G\int_{V(R)}  dV = -\rho(r_0) \cdot \frac{4 \pi G R^3}{3r_0^2}
$$

Comment: Can I just ask, how did you evaluate $g(r)ê_r$?

Comment: If $\vec{g}(\vec{r}) = g(r) \hat{e}_r$ then $g$ is constant over the sphere, and the normal is radial, so we can take it out of the integral, and the integral is just the area of the sphere

Comment: Could you also explain, really briefly, why we use $R$ as the radius in the triple-integral only in the case of $r_0>R$?

Comment: Because $\rho(r)=0$ for $r>R$